# Retrieve excel cell background color using perl excel win32 ole

Tags: perl, excel, win32ole

I need to retrieve the background color of an excel cell (set to red/green based on a conditional formatting in the sheet). Tried searching the forums but couldnt find anything to retrieve although setting the colors are there.
Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You need `$Range->Interior()->ColorIndex();`

Here is sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Win32::OLE;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

my $ex;
eval { $ex = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') };
die "Excel not installed" if $@;
unless ( defined $ex ) {
    $ex = Win32::OLE->new( 'Excel.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit; } )
      or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
}

my $book = $ex->Workbooks->Open("$Bin/test_background.xls");

my $sheet = $book->Worksheets(1);
my $Range = $sheet->Range("A1:A1");
say $Range->Interior()->ColorIndex();

$Range = $sheet->Range("B1:B1");
say $Range->Interior()->ColorIndex();

$Range = $sheet->Range("C1:C1");
say $Range->Interior()->ColorIndex();
```

The output for this file[image]
is this:

```
3
6
3
```

Comment: thanks. but as i mentioned the color is set based on conditional formatting. will this work for that also?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure but you can try.